# Why does VolatileImage have no set/getPixel() method

Tags: java, 3d, rendering

I am a relative newbie in game programming. I know how to draw pixels to a `BufferedImage` using `setPixel()`. It is horribly slow on larger formats so I moved on and found `VolatileImage` (took me a week or so). It is fairly easy to draw lines, strings, rects, etc but I can't draw individual pixels. I already tried using `drawLine(x,y,x,y)` but I get 3-4 FPS on an 800x600 image.
The fact that java didn't include `setPixel()` or `setRGB()` in the `VolatileImage` makes me pretty angry and confused.

I have 4 questions:

1. Is there a way to draw individual pixels on a VolatileImage? (on 1440x900 formats with FPS > 40)
2. Can I draw pixels in a BufferedImage with a faster method? (same 1440x900, FPS > 40)
3. Is there any other way to draw pixels fast enough for 3D games?
4. Can I make my BufferedImage hardware accelerated( tried using `setAccelerationPriority(1F)` but it doesn't work)

Please if you have any idea tell me. I can't continue making my game wihout this information. I already made 3D rendering algorithms but i need to be able to draw fast pixels. I have got a good feeling about this game.

Here's the code if it can help you help me:

```
public static void drawImageRendered (int x, int y, int w, int h) { // This is just a method to test the performance

    int a[] = new int[3]; // The array containing R, G and B value for each pixel
    bImg = Launcher.contObj.getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(800, 600); // Creates a compatible image for the JPanel object i am working with (800x600)
    bImg.setAccelerationPriority(1F); // I am trying to get this image accelerated
    WritableRaster wr = bImg.getRaster(); // The image's writable raster
    for (int i = 0; i < bImg.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bImg.getHeight(); j++) {
            a[0] = i % 256;
            a[2] = j % 256;
            a[1] = (j * i) % 256;
            wr.setPixel(i, j, a); // Sets the pixels (You get a nice pattern)
        }
    }
    g.drawImage(bImg, x, y, w, h, null);
}
```

I would much prefer not using *OpenGL* or any other external libraries, just plain Java.

Comment: Good work dude, well I don't know how are you going to draw the target image, but I don't have problem with refresh time by buffered image and painting (exactly with pure pixels setRGB()), [this example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#lc) may help, it's about a something like screen saver, and I've got over 60 FPS with just CPU, over 500 FPS with GPU

Comment: Still didn't find anything that could help me

Comment: so do you draw the image in a parallel manner? how do you manage the target image/frame drawing dude?

Answer (score 1):

Well you're basically drawing one pixel after the other *using the CPU*. There's no way that this can be accelerated, thus such a method does simply not make any sense for a VolatileImage. The low FPS you get suggest that this even causes a significant overhead, as each pixel drawing operation is sent to the graphics card (with information such as location & colour), which takes longer than to modify 3 or 4 bytes of RAM.

I suggest to either stop drawing each pixel separately or to figure out a way to make your drawing algorithm run directly on the graphics card (which most likely requires another language than Java).

Answer (score 1):

It's been over 4 years since this post got an answer. I was looking for an answer to this question as well and stumbled on this post. After some more searching, I got it to work. Below I'll post the source to rendering pixels with a VolatileImage.

It seems Java hides our ability to plot pixels directly to a VolatileImage, but we can draw buffered images to it. For good reason. Using the software to plot a pixel doesn't really help with acceleration(in Java it seems). If you can plot pixels to a BufferedImage, and then render it on a VolatileImage, you may get a speed bonus since it's hardware accelerated from that point.

The source down below is a self-contained example. You can copy-pasta practically all of it to your project and run it.

https://github.com/Miekpeeps/JavaSnippets-repo/blob/master/src/graphics_rendering/pixels_03/PlottingVolatile.java

In the constructor I save the Graphics environment of the app/game.

```
private GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
private GraphicsConfiguration gc = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
```

Then, when I call a method to enable hardware we create a buffer. I set the transparency to Opaque. In my little engine, I deal with transparency/alpha blending on another thread in the pipeline.

```
public void setHardwareAcceleration(Boolean hw) 
{
    useHW = hw;
    if (hw)
    {
        vbuffer = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(width, height, Transparency.OPAQUE);
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", hw.toString()); // may not be needed.
    }
}
```

For each frame I update, I get the Graphics from the VolatileImage and render my buffer there. Nothing gets rendered if I dont flush().

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    if(useHW) 
    {
        g = vbuffer.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
        vbuffer.flush();
    } 
    else 
    {
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
        buffer.flush();
    }
}
```

There is still a little bit of overhead when calling to plot a pixel on the BufferedImage writable raster. But when we update the screen, we get a speed boost when using the Volatile image instead of using the Buffered image.

Hope this helps some folks out. Cheers.